# Splitting the string[]

Tags: java, arrays, string

UPDATE:

the output sould be:

```
chapter: Chapter 01
title: one
code: 111111

chapter: Chapter 02
title: two
code: 222222

chapter: Chapter 03
title: three
code: 333333

chapter: Chapter 04
title: four
code: 444444

chapter: Chapter 05
title: five
code: 555555
```

I have this code to split a string[]. I am not sure what the problem is. can anybody help me please?

```
String[] myArray = "Chapter 01<<<one<<<111111:::Chapter 02<<<two<<<222222:::Chapter 03<<<three<<<33333:::Chapter 04<<<four<<<4444:::Chapter 05<<<five<<<5555:::"
```

just for the sake of simplicity i have make the dummy `String[]`

```
for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++)
{
String[] songs = myArray[j].split("\\<<<");

System.out.println("chapter: " + songs[0]);
System.out.println("title: " + songs[1]);
System.out.println("code: " + songs[2]);
}
```

so what i want to see in the result is:

```
chapter: Chapter 01
title: one
code: 111111
............so on and so forth........
```

Comment: You say what you *want* the output to be, but what does it actually output?

Comment: Please Post your Output.What you getting.

Comment: why cannt you use StringTokenizer instead of split. it has three constructors which will helps you.

Comment: looked like homework, feels like homework, tagged as homework.

Comment: Are you trying to split a String or values of String array?
Please provide an exact example of the String you are trying to split.
The above example you provided is confusing beacause you are declaring a String array but assigning String to it.

Comment: oh i wish its homework... i missed those days lol

Comment: Your first line is not `String[]` its `String` and be specific about your output, is it required or what you get?

Comment: can post your error and what kind of output you want.

Comment: It seems, that you have a String to split not String array

Comment: JProgrammer resolved your issue, you can take that as fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void splitString(){
    String[] myArray = "Chapter 01<<<one<<<111111:::Chapter 02<<<two<<<222222:::Chapter 03<<<three<<<33333:::Chapter 04<<<four<<<4444:::Chapter 05<<<five<<<5555:::".split(":::");
    for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++)
    {
        String[] songs = myArray[j].split("<<<");

        System.out.println("chapter: " + songs[0]);
        System.out.println("title: " + songs[1]);
        System.out.println("code: " + songs[2]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: @paislee. I wrote that method in eclipse, compiled it and run it. I saw the output and it is what expected in the question AND THEN ONLY POSTED HERE. you should have look CAREFULLY.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help:

```
public class Tmp {

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    String myArray = 
      "Chapter 01<<<one<<<111111:::Chapter 02<<<two<<<222222:::Chapter 03<<<three<<<33333";

    String[] chapters = myArray.split (":::");
    for (int i=0; i < chapters.length; i++) {
      System.out.println ("chapters[" + i + "]: " + chapters[i] + "...");

      String[] sections = chapters[i].split ("<<<");
      for (int j=0; j < sections.length; j++)
        System.out.println ("  sections[" + j + "]: " + sections[j] + "...");
    }
  }

}

java Tmp
chapters[0]: Chapter 01<<<one<<<111111...
  sections[0]: Chapter 01...
  sections[1]: one...
  sections[2]: 111111...
chapter[s1]: Chapter 02<<<two<<<222222...
  sections[0]: Chapter 02...
  sections[1]: two...
  sections[2]: 222222...
chapters[2]: Chapter 03<<<three<<<33333...
  sections[0]: Chapter 03...
  sections[1]: three...
  sections[2]: 33333...
```

Comment: +1 By looking out the output, this looks like the solution to the question that was not asked correctly :)

Comment: so you saying i am missing `[]` in the output?  how come i have not asked correctly?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Stringss {

public static void main(String[] args){
    String myString = "Chapter 01<<<one<<<111111:::" +
            "Chapter 02<<<two<<<222222:::" +
            "Chapter 03<<<three<<<33333:::" +
            "Chapter 04<<<four<<<4444:::" +
            "Chapter 05<<<five<<<5555:::";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myString,":::");
    String[] songs;
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        String token = st.nextToken();
        songs = token.split("\\<<<");

        System.out.println("chapter: " + songs[0]);
        System.out.println("title: " + songs[1]);
        System.out.println("code: " + songs[2]);

        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post correct questions- See comment from @Nirmal et all.

Use split multiple times. First using ::: as line/section marker.  The use "<<<" song entry delimiter. That is the answer from @Paul, just writing this answer so clarify those steps..